# Error on observer while running replication hook 'before_commit'. On 200k rows update

Tags: mysql

I have script to encrypt columns in table. >200k rows. On 100k its working.

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(col1, @keyBase, @static_iv)), 
col2 = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(col2 , @keyBase, @static_iv))
```

Edit: I reproduced this on more simple example (>200k records):

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Plan A:** What "Error"?  Probably a timelimit.  That is a setting that can be changed.

**Plan B:** I prefer to do massive updates 1000 rows at a time.
The following discusses how
to walk through the table using the `PRIMARY KEY` to do `DELETEs`.  A similar technique works well for `UPDATEs. https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

**Plan C:** Do the conversion while copying the table over.  This will run faster than the `UPDATE`.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table;
INSERT INTO table2
            (col1, col2, ...other columns...)
    SELECT  TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(col1, @keyBase, @static_iv)), 
            TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(col2, @keyBase, @static_iv)),
            ...other columns...
        FROM table;
RENAME TABLE table2 TO table_old,
             table TO table2;
DROP TABLE table_old;
```

**UUIDs** If the `PRIMARY KEY` is a UUID, then method B needs the "big gap" solution mentioned in the above link:

```
SELECT @z := uuid FROM tbl WHERE uuid >= @a ORDER BY uuid LIMIT 1000,1
```

finds the thousandth item hence.

Comment: A: "Error on observer while running replication hook 'before_commit'" this is full message which get.  On MySQL WorkBench i extended timeout to 10 min. Query fail to in about 30 sec.
B: i have already read this. Problem is in update you are not allowed to limit (offset, top). Another problem is that as key we only use guid so i cannot use where id > c && id < c + 1000

Comment: @cargt4 - I added a note on how to step over 1000 rows without being able to use arithmetic.

Comment: thx. after some required changes it started working. Now i faced another problem. For on of the tables identity id need to be encrypted